# S3 Upload error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

When i upload file in s3 using CI I got the error message           `Message: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file:filename.jpg`

Here is my code

```
$time = Time();
if(!empty($_FILES['productImage']['name'])){
$file_name        =  $_FILES['productImage']['name'];
$productImageName = 'PRD_'.$time.$_FILES['productImage']['name'];
 if ($this->s3->putObjectFile($file_name, "bucketname", $productImageName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
   echo "We successfully uploaded your file.";exit;
 }else{
    echo "Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.";exit;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai  I got another solution for uploading file in s3 using CI .Here i share the code .It will helpful for someone in future

code from github  : https://github.com/fcosrno/aws-sdk-php-codeigniter

And my code :

```
$this->load->library('aws_sdk');
try{
   $aws_object=$this->aws_sdk->saveObject(array(
   'Bucket'      => 'mybucket',
   'Key'         => 'QA/product/'.$newImagename,
   'ACL'         => 'public-read',
   'SourceFile'  => $_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'],
   'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
))->toArray();

}catch (Exception $e){
  $error = "Something went wrong saving your file.\n".$e;
  echo $error;
}
```